# Visual Studio 2010 can't see /bin library of OpenCV

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, bin

I'm trying to use OpenCv 2.2 in Visual Studio 2010.

I've configured everything by instruction: 
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B

and by instruction from the book:

So I've added all /lib and /include paths.

When I build project, it compiles and before starting app, VS displays an error message that `opencv_core220d.dll` is missing.

This file is in `C:/OpenCV2.2/bin` as all `.dll` files. If I add this file to my working directory - it will be fine. Then VS displays error about every `.dll` file that I added in Linker-Input configuration ( but with `.lib` extension ).

So, if I add all `.dlls` file that I've added as `.lib` in Linker configuration  - to my working directory, project will start.

But why? Why VC doesn't see `OpenCV2.2/bin` folder? Where is this pointed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it doesn't know to look there by default. However, it does know to check the current directory for the DLLs.

You can tell it where to look by adding `C:/OpenCV2.2/bin` to your `Path` variable, or if you would rather not muck up your global `Path` you can set the Environment variable local to the C++ project.

[image]

I think that is the syntax for appending to the `Path` in VS2010, but I'm not sure, so Google it if that doesn't work :)